# Is there such a thing as unbuffered registered DIMM memory?

Tags: memory, ecc

I thought the two (registered and buffered, and the same for the negations) are synonymous. Are there any ECC unbuffered but registered modules out there?

Comment: Why are you asking? Is this for a particular make/model of server hardware? Wikipedia does explain it well, though: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_memory

Comment: You are right, I have read the Wikipedia article and my understanding was that the two are synonymous. I have however been sold some modules that have been marketed as Unbuffered, but they are registered and the [allegedly] reputable seller claims that this is the case. I am a little ashamed to ask a stupid question, but I am asking because: 1) my understanding of the Wiki article could be wrong and 2) the wikipedia article could be wrong as well.  The module in question is a Kingston dimm with this part no: KVR1333D3D8R9S/4G

Comment: Well, if you're using branded server hardware, the options are usually dictated by the manufacturer. That's why I asked about the server(s) involved.

Comment: Right. The memory modules in question are Kingston KVR1333D3D8R9S/4G http://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/KVR1333D3D8R9S_4G.pdf   The server I am trying to use it on is an HP Z400 but I am only interested if I am right or wrong about the principle that unbuffered = unregistered when it comes to memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little more researching I have convinced myself that they are as good as synonymous. All buffered memory is registered and vice versa.